# Can I Banish a druid when he's in elemental form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid

Is it possible to cast *banishment* or *dismissal* on a druid when he is wild-shaped into an elemental?

Comment: Hi Francesco, please reserve `code markup` for actual code - use *Italics* or something to indicate spells and technical terms if you need to

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not with the intent to send them to an elemental plane.

Wild Shape, as it pertains to elementals, is the equivalent of [Elemental Body](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/elementalBody.html#elemental-body-i). In this spell, you assume the form of an elemental, you do not fully become one. You remain planar, as your origin is still in the default plane, regardless of the form you assume.

Answer (score 7):

Banishment only works on extraplanar creatures and it sends them to their Home Plane.
So if your Druid happens to be extraplanar like say an Assimar, then yes, but not because they are in elemental form, only because they are in fact extraplanar.  If the druid is from the material plane, first they are not extraplanar and second they are already in their home plane.
Spell descriptors:
"It enables you to force extraplanar creatures out of your home plane."
"Will save or be banished back to its home plane."

Comment: Technically, aasimar are not extraplanar. They are outsiders with the native subtype not the extraplanar subtype.

Comment: Aasimars and Tieflings aren't extraplanar for the purposes of banishment, as they have the Native subtype.

Comment: I stand corrected native does mean their home is the material plane.  Bad choice for example.

Answer (score 4):

No. The wild shape ability allows the druid to assume the form and certain abilities of an elemental but not the crucial bit needed for banishing. The druid's creature type remains the same - he/she does not become an outsider with the extraplanar subtype. For something to be banished (with *dismissal* or *banishment* for instance), the creature must have the extraplanar subtype.